# Phonegap crushes on external page load

Tags: android, cordova

I'm in the very beginning with phonegap (2.2.0). In my index.html I have a iframe to load a external facebook page, it's just a dummy page, and most of the cases it loads pretty well. But when it fails do load (didn't get it why) the entire application crushes. The iframe is loading after all the other itens of the page are loaded and when it timeouts, app crushes. I firstr tried the src on the iframe tag as well with the same result (changed to better test)

The url loading:

```
jQuery("#facebookIframe").attr({"src" : "https://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fcocacola&colorscheme=light&show_faces=true&border_color=%23fff&stream=false&header=false&height=186"})
```

The iframe

```
<div id="facebookFrame" style="text-align: center; width: 99%;">
<iframe id="facebookIframe" style="border: none; width: 90%;" ></iframe>
</div>
```

For the record, I'm using android and the error messages I get are:

"The connection to the server was unsuccessful." and TIMEOUT ERROR!

Thanks

Comment: Did you add facebook.com to the domain white list?

Comment: Yup

<access origin="https://www.facebook.com/*" />
<access origin="http://www.facebook.com/*" />

It is still a presentation, so I made a fake for now.